# Fail to use git pull “Couldn't find remote ref –-allow-unrelated-histories”

Tags: windows, git, github

push to github,but merge fail,Fail to use git pull "Couldn't find remote ref allow-unrelated-histories"

I come up with a problem about git pull.
first,I 'm add remote,

```
git init 
git add .
git remote add origin https://github.com/xxx/xxxx.git
```

success
Then I use git push
and got an error message,

`refusing to merge unrelated histories`
so i use below,but got extra message

```
git pull origin master --allow-unrelated-histories
```

Fail to use git pull "Couldn't find remote ref allow-unrelated-histories" 
Oh,god,I don't know what to do,please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Options to `pull` (such as the merge option `--allow-unrelated-histories`) must come before the remote name and refspec, because there could be any number of refspec arguments.

```
git pull --allow-unrelated-histories origin master
```

However, unless you know why you are combining unrelated histories, this may not be a good idea.  It is not typical that you would need to do this, and instead of chasing error messages you may need to take a step back and be sure it's totally clear why the original pull isn't doing what you expected.

Comment: Thanks )). The solution worked. But I not sure have good way to merge local and remote repositories with different names